# Populate channel field based on other fields arithmetics

Tags: fields, pre-populate, math

Let's assume I have a “products” channel which contains 3 fields: price(number), discount(integer 1 to 100), discounted_price(number).

Is there a way to populate the discounted_price field in CP, based on price - (price * discount / 100)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to handle this using jQuery/JavaScript in your field's instructions.

You can include HTML in the Instructions field for your custom field. So you can include:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Do some stuff
</script>
```

You can set your code to fire onblur on your fields, so that every time a field is updated, the JS runs, and calculates the value for the other field.

You can do a View Source on the entry screen to find all the field references you need for your jQuery code.

Comment: This is rather interesting… fairly brilliant solution. I didn't know the description field accepted html/jscript. I'll test it.

Comment: It's a fairly common solution once it's realized :)